# Is there a way to see the running cost of all the AWS services that I use / free tier usage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have recently started to experiment with AWS Amplify to write and host web apps.
I am using the free tier, and one month I had elastic search almost exceed my free usage credit. I didn't even know I had used elastic search, but I guess one of the examples I tried did.

I can't find a way to see all the AWS services that I have running.

I contacted AWS support and that didn't answer my question. I still don't know where to look to see a full list of services that I have running.

Answer (score 2):

#### Costs & Usage of All Services

To keep track of all the services you are currently being billed for, go to the [Cost Explorer dashboard](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cost-management/home?#/dashboard) in which you can use to visualize, understand, and manage your AWS costs and usage over a daily or monthly granularity.

[image]

---

#### Costs & Usage of Services Eligible for the AWS Free Tier

To keep track of how much you have used from your services that have a free tier quota, go to [Billing and Cost Management console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home) > **Top Free Tier Services by Usage**.

There's a usage table with information about the services you've used eligible for the free tier, the respective quota limit & a month-to-date usage column allowing you to see how much % you've used so far.

[image]

For more information including forecasted usage or if you need search functionality, click on the **View all** button which will take you to the [dedicated AWS Free Tier page](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?#/freetier).

[image]